# My image does not occupy the entire body and leaves blank spaces HTML/CSS Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

When I put an image I try to make it occupy the entire body but it leaves blank spaces.

My code is this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('../assets/img/food-with-ingredients.jpg'); -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover !important; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat !important;">
```

My image stays like this.

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcAPb.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Is this `div` the area below the nav bar? You can set its height to be the remaining size of the screen. Could we know what is the height of the nav bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try set the `min-height` of this `div` to be the remaining size of the screen.

The remaining size can be got by doing a `calc()` of `100vh` minus the height of the navigation bar.

Example:

```
<div
  style="
    min-height: calc(
      100vh - 80px
    ); /*      change 80px to the height of nav bar */
    background-image: url('../assets/img/food-with-ingredients.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  "
></div>
```

Comment: Es perfecto, gracias!!